# my join query returns inncorrect values

Tags: sql-server, database, join

i am having problem when I query the sql server to retrieve records from different three tables its performing totally incorrect values for `SUM([Bills.Extrabill_dollar])` and `SUM([Receipts.Amount])`, bellow is my query please help me.

```
select Customers.SNO, SUM(Bills.Extrabill_dollar) as [ExtraAmount],SUM(Receipts.Amount) as [Received]
from
Customers left join Bills on Customers.SNO=Bills.CustomerSNO
left join Receipts on Customers.SNO=Receipts.CSNO
group by Customers.SNO
```

but if i use bellow two separate queries to return **SUM(Extra_dollar)** and **SUM(Extra_dollar)**
`SELECT Bills.CustomerSNO as [CustomerSNO],
SUM(Bills.Extrabill_dollar) AS [TotalExtraAmount] from Bills
group by Bills.CustomerSNO`

`SELECT Receipts.CSNO as [CustomerSNO],
SUM(Receipts.Amount) AS [TotalReveied] from Receipts
group by Receipts.CSNO`  the correct results will be returned which won't be returned if combine these tables by using **JOIN**, please help me Dears.

Comment: Do we have to guess the `totally incorrect values`? Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear all thanks for your help, after long journey i found **the answer**:

```
select c.SNO, c.CName, 
isnull((select SUM(PricePerKwt_dollar) from Bills
where Bills.CustomerSNO =c.SNO),0.00) as [TotalBills],
isnull((select SUM(Receipts.Amount) from Receipts
where Receipts.CSNO = c.SNO),0.00) as [TotalReceipts]
 from Customers c
```

Answer (score 0):

By saying that you got incorrect answers, I wouldn't know.

I think since you're using LEFT JOIN, it might be causing the problem.
Left join takes all the values from Customers, even the unmatched rows will be present, which will be mapped to NULL values under Bills and Receipts.

You can use this code and try it out.

```
SELECT Customers.SNO
, SUM(Bills.Extrabill_dollar) AS [ExtraAmount]
, SUM(Receipts.Amount) AS [Received]
FROM
Customers INNER JOIN Bills 
ON Customers.SNO=Bills.CustomerSNO
INNER JOIN Receipts 
ON Customers.SNO=Receipts.CSNO
GROUP BY Customers.SNO
```

Comment: Dear @Vishnu with full respect your answer not solved my issue, you only removed the null columns but the [ExtraAmount] and [Received] values are still incorrect, still need your help

Comment: when i run separate queries (without joining BILLS and RECEIPTS tables) to get [ExtraAmount] and [Received], that will give the correct values but when i use join thats when i getting the incorrect values

Comment: You need to tell me what you're getting and what you're expecting. Just saying correct and incorrect values I'm unable to understand.

Comment: for exmple i am getting **SUM(Extra_dollar)** = 34 and **SUM(Amount)** = 12  where **Customer.SNO=2** ,  but i am expecting to get  **SUM(Extra_dollar)** = 17 and **SUM(Amount)** = 4 where **Customer.SNO=2**

Answer (score 0):

```
select Customers.SNO, SUM(Bills.Extrabill_dollar) as [ExtraAmount],SUM(Receipts.Amount) as [Received]
from
Customers right join Bills on Customers.SNO=Bills.CustomerSNO
right join Receipts on Customers.SNO=Receipts.CSNO
group by Customers.SNO
```

Comment: Dear @Ashu  bellow message displayed: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where".

Comment: "The multi-part identifier "Customer.SNO" could not be bound" again saying this.

Comment: if RUN bellow two queries they will return the correct values 
`SELECT Receipts.CSNO as [CustomerSNO],
Receipts.Amount as [RceivedAmount] from Receipts`

`SELECT Bills.CustomerSNO as [CustomerSNO],
Bills.Extrabill_dollar from Bills`

Comment: it shows nothing because i don't have customer which has **SNO=1**

Comment: i want to get all customers with their **SUM(Bills.Extra_dollar)** and **SUM(Receipts.Amount)**

Comment: I cannot understand what output do you want from query, Please edit your question and explain more about what result you want